# How to use Timer Elapsed event in Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, timer

I have some threads and I want to use timer's elapsed events in these threads. All timer's elapsed events should work in different thread.

For example :

```
     Thread thDoviz = new Thread(OntmrDoviz_Elapsed);

     private static Timer tmrDoviz = new Timer(3600000);

     private static void OntmrDoviz_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("sdf");

     }
```

I know this code wouldn't work, how should I set my codes?

Comment: If you use a `System.Threading.Timer`, it *does* run in a different thread. Can you describe what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
 private static Timer tmrDoviz = new Timer(3600000);
 tmrDoviz.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OntmrDoviz_Elapsed);


 private static void OntmrDoviz_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
    Thread thDoviz = new Thread(SomeOtherFunctionToRunFromThread);
    thDoviz .Start();
 }
```